# How to remove unused function parameters in shutil.rmtree

Tags: python, pylint

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21261132/shutil-rmtree-to-remove-readonly-files), an answer to how to remove read-only files is presented. It's super effective but requires having unused parameters. In [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47059273/how-to-indicate-multiple-unused-values-in-python) it was asked how to tell pylint that multiple non-adjacent parameters are unused without adding a specific comment (e.g., by using `_`). Many of the answers were approximately "ZOMG YOU'RE DESIGNING IT WRONG" so I promised I would put up an example where this is needed and out of my control. Here is that example.

```
shutil.rmtree(self._temp_dir, onerror=del_rw)

def del_rw(action, name, exc):
    os.chmod(name, stat.S_IWRITE)
    os.remove(name)
```

The "answer" so that pylint would not complain about `action` and `exc` is to

```
shutil.rmtree(self._temp_dir, onerror=del_rw)

def del_rw(_action, name, _exc):
    os.chmod(name, stat.S_IWRITE)
    os.remove(name)
```

but the new question is, how to do this without having `_action` or `_exc` as parameters?

Comment: Prefix with `cb_`? As in `def cb_del_rw`, as this answer mentions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47059273/how-to-indicate-multiple-unused-values-in-python

Comment: You have to have the parameters, because `rmtree()` calls the function with those parameters, even though you ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, you cannot just ignore `action`, and `exc` because `rmtree` will pass those arguments to the callback. From the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree):

> If `onerror` is provided, it must be a **callable** that accepts *three*
>   parameters: `function`, `path`, and `excinfo`.

That being said, you have a couple of options:

- You can prefix the callback with a `cb_` (see [pylint docs](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#i-have-a-callback-function-where-i-have-no-control-over-received-arguments-how-do-i-avoid-getting-unused-argument-warnings) on this as well), turning your function into:

  ```
  shutil.rmtree(self._temp_dir, onerror=cb_del_rw)

  def cb_del_rw(action, name, exc):
      os.chmod(name, stat.S_IWRITE)
      os.remove(name)
  ```
- You can use [keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) (you could also use `*args`, but I find this approach more readable):

  ```
  shutil.rmtree(self._temp_dir, onerror=del_rw)

  def del_rw(**kwargs):
      name = kwargs['name']
      os.chmod(name, stat.S_IWRITE)
      os.remove(name)
  ```