# How to create multiple objects from array of entries in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

**I receive an array of entries from form** using FormData(). It consists of information about the recipe. Like this:

```
const dataArr = [
  ['title', 'pizza'],
  ['image', 'url'],
  ['quantity-0', '1'],
  ['unit-0', 'kg'],
  ['description-0', 'Flour'],
  ['quantity-1', '2'],
  ['unit-1', 'tbsp'],
  ['description-1', 'Olive oil'],
  ... // more ingredients
];
```

**which I need to reorganize in new object**, like this:

```
const recipe = {
  title: 'pizza',
  image: 'url',
  ingredients: [
    { quantity: '1', unit: 'kg', ingredient: 'Flour' },
    { quantity: '2', unit: 'tbsp', ingredient: 'Olive oil' },
    ...
  ],
};
```

So, for ingredients array **I need to create multiple objects from received data.** I came up with needed result, but it's not clean. **I would appreciate your help coming up with universal function, when number of ingredients is unknown.**

My solution: Form receives 6 ingredients max, therefore:

```
const ingredients = [];

// 1. Create an array with length of 6 (index helps to get ingredient-related data looping over the array)
const arrayOf6 = new Array(6).fill({});

arrayOf6.forEach((_, i) => {

  // 2. In each iteration filter over all data to get an array for each ingredient
  const ingArr = dataArr.filter(entry => {
    return entry[0].startsWith(`unit-${i}`) ||
    entry[0].startsWith(`quantity-${i}`) ||
    entry[0].startsWith(`ingredient-${i}`);
  });

  // 3. Loop over each ingredient array and rename future properties
  ingArr.forEach(entry => {
    [key, value] = entry;

    if(key.includes('ingredient')) entry[0] = 'description';
    if(key.includes('quantity')) entry[0] = 'quantity';
    if(key.includes('unit')) entry[0] = 'unit';
  });

  // 4. Transform array to object and push into ingredients array
  const ingObj = Object.fromEntries(ingArr);
  ingredients.push(ingObj);
});

// To finalize new object
const dataObj = Object.fromEntries(dataArr);
const recipe = {
  title: dataObj.title,
  image: dataObj.image,
  ingredients,
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to parse the values of the input array to extract the index. To build the result object, you could use `reduce`:

```js
const dataArr = [['title', 'pizza'],['image', 'url'],['quantity-0', '1'],['unit-0', 'kg'],['description-0', 'Flour'],['quantity-1', '2'],['unit-1', 'tbsp'], ['description-1', 'Olive oil']];

const recipe = dataArr.reduce((recipe, [name, value]) => {
  const [, prop, index] = name.match(/^(\w+)-(\d+)$/) ?? [];
  if (prop) {
    (recipe.ingredients[index] ??= {})[prop] = value;
  } else {
    recipe[name] = value;
  }
  return recipe;
}, { ingredients: [] });

console.log(recipe);
```

Comment: (Because I've seen several of your answers which demonstrate advanced JS knowledge,) I am almost certain that you are aware that unused destructured array element variables can be elided in your assignment (`const [, prop, index] = /*....*/` rather than using `_`). Do you use it anyway as a code style choice? If so, what do you use when there are multiple unusused in one statement (or later in the same block)?

Comment: Yes, you're right. It would not work with multiple `_`. I think I took this habit from Python... So I'll go with just the comma here. Thanks!

Comment: Sure; thanks for sharing that bit about Python — I'm not as familiar with its syntax because I rarely use it: would you say that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47061782/438273) is idiomatic?

Comment: Opinions will differ, but yes, that looks like how it would be done.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `arrayOf6`. You never use its elements for anything -- it seems like you're just using it as a replacement for a loop like `for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++)`.

Just loop over `dataArr` and check whether the name has a number at the end. If it does, use that as an index into the ingredients array, otherwise use the name as the property of the `ingredients` object. Then you don't need to hard-code a limit to the number of ingredients.

```js
const dataArr = [
  ['title', 'pizza'],
  ['image', 'url'],
  ['quantity-0', '1'],
  ['unit-0', 'kg'],
  ['description-0', 'Flour'],
  ['quantity-1', '2'],
  ['unit-1', 'tbsp'],
  ['description-1', 'Olive oil'],
  // more ingredients
];

const recipe = {
  ingredients: []
};

dataArr.forEach(([name, value]) => {
  let match = name.match(/^(\w+)-(\d+)$/);
  if (match) {
    let type = match[1];
    let index = match[2];
    if (!recipe.ingredients[index]) {
      recipe.ingredients[index] = {};
    }
    recipe.ingredients[index][type] = value;
  } else {
    recipe[name] = value;
  }
});

console.log(recipe);
```

Answer (score 0):

Separating the key-parsing logic helps me think about the concerns more clearly:

```js
const orderedKeyRegExp = /^(.+)-(\d+)$/;

function parseKey (key) {
  const match = key.match(orderedKeyRegExp);
  // Return -1 for the index if the key pattern isn't part of a numbered sequence
  if (!match) return {index: -1, name: key};
  return {
    index: Number(match[2]),
    name: match[1],
  };
}

function transformRecipeEntries (entries) {
  const result = {};
  const ingredients = [];

  for (const [key, value] of entries) {
    const {index, name} = parseKey(key);
    if (index >= 0) (ingredients[index] ??= {})[name] = value;
    //               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // Assign an empty object to the element of the array at the index
    // (if it doesn't already exist)
    else result[name] = value;
  }

  if (ingredients.length > 0) result.ingredients = ingredients;
  return result;
}

const entries = [
  ['title', 'pizza'],
  ['image', 'url'],
  ['quantity-0', '1'],
  ['unit-0', 'kg'],
  ['description-0', 'Flour'],
  ['quantity-1', '2'],
  ['unit-1', 'tbsp'],
  ['description-1', 'Olive oil'],
  // ...more ingredients
];

const result = transformRecipeEntries(entries);
console.log(result);
```